# Getting recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

The following issue happens only when i use Laravel's @include to include other blade templates into main layout:

/etc/nginx/error.log

> > 015/06/25 23:42:34 [error] 3374#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection
> >     reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:
> >     192.168.33.1, server: dev.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host:
> >     "local.dev.com"
>
> 2015/06/25 23:42:34 [error] 3374#0:*1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.33.1, server: dev.com,request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host:"local.dev.com"

php5-fpm.log doesnt report any issues

I already tried:

```
opcache.enable=0 

proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
proxy_send_timeout  600s;
proxy_read_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Nothing helped so far. Only if I remove @include from template.

I use:

- laravel 5.1
- vagrant
- nginx 1.4.6
- php5-fpm

I'm completely wrecked by this issue. Loosing my head for 5hrs already. Any help is well appreciated. If you need me to post anything else, let me know.

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Comment: @matteo T. How did you resolve this error?